# Launching a new microservice that consumes other microservices' events

Tags: distributed-computing, event-sourcing

I was concerned about this problem:
suppose you have an already existent microservice environment and you want to launch a new microservice that offers new functionalities. If this microservices needs to consumes old events to provide its functionalities how this should be handled?

Suppose you want to launch a recommendation service that need to consume user related events, how can it get old events?

On a event sourcing based architecture you could query the Event Store, but tipically the ES is organized in *event streams* and is difficult keep track of all the existent streams in order to query all the events.

My idea was to keep an eventual consistent repository where I store all the events in the order they happened (let's call it *event history*). Launching a new MS, it will subscribe to the topics of interest and query the *event history* until a certain point.
It feels like I'm duplicating unnecessary data and I was looking for better solutions.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think querying the event store is the way to go.  Any event store *should* provide some method to read **all** of the events, regardless of stream.  (Some may also have a "give me all events for aggregates of type X" too... but there should be an "all" option at a minimum.)

So I would spin up the new service and have it query and subscribe to all of the events in the event store - process the ones you care about and ignore the others.  You only need to the initial history pull the first time (or if you need to rebuild), after that you're just working with the current events (as your new service can maintain some state for itself).

Using a separate "event history" repository would just be kicking the can down the road a little bit - you would still have to seed *that* repo and have the same problem all over again.

If you had *multiple* services that all only needed a specific set of event/data types, then it might make sense to have a separate "filter repo" that could pull events from the store and keep just the necessary ones.  Then services could get their data from the pre-filtered data instead of directly from the store.  The complexity vs. performance trade off would have to be looked at on a per-system basis though!